# How do I tell mypy to load dotenv from my site-packages?

Tags: python, mypy

How do I tell mypy the location of a package?  The package is in site-packages.

Details:

I am getting this error

```
% mypy t.py 
t.py:10: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named "dotenv"  [import]
```

on this code

```
import dotenv
dotenv.load_dotenv(dotenv.find_dotenv())
```

I see the dotenv module in my sys.path:

```
>>> sys.path
['', '/Users/mark/miniconda3/lib/python311.zip', '/Users/mark/miniconda3/lib/python3.11', '/Users/mark/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload', '/Users/mark/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages']

% ls /Users/mark/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dotenv 
__init__.py __pycache__/    ipython.py  parser.py   variables.py
__main__.py cli.py      main.py     py.typed    version.py
```

What can I do to tell mypy about the location of this package?